# How to get unique rows in one file comparing with multiple files in awk

Tags: awk

I have tab-delimited files as shown below and would like to get the output as described below. I tried to some extent with the below commands but could not reach the final task. The description is slightly lengthy to make the question clear.

#### file1.txt

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ID1  str1  234  cond1  0 
ID1  str2  567  cond1  0
ID1  str3  789  cond1  1
ID1  str4  123  cond1  1
```

#### file2.txt

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ID2  str1  235  cond1  0 
ID2  str2  567  cond2  1
ID2  str3  789  cond1  1 
ID2  str4  123  cond2  0
```

#### file3.txt

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ID3  str1  235  cond1  0 
ID3  str2  567  cond2  1
ID3  str3  789  cond1  1
```

I would like to find the unique rows in `file1.txt` when compared with rest of the files, `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`. Columns `col2` and `col3` are used as keys to search. I have an additional condition to delete only if `col4="cond1"` though the keys `col2` and `col3` are found in `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`. Below is the code and output:

```
 awk -F "\t" 'NR == 1  { OFS="\t"; print $0; next }
              NR == FNR { a[$2,$3] = $0; next }
              { if ($4=="cond1") delete a[$2, $3] }
              END { for (i in a) print a[i] }' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Output:

```
 col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
 ID1  str1  234  cond1  0 
 ID1  str2  567  cond1  0 
 ID1  str4  123  cond1  0
```

Now, I would like to add additional columns with a list of `col1` values and a count of `col1` values from the files which do not meet the condition `$4=="cond1"` in `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`.

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
 col1    col2    col3  col4    col5    col6  col7
 ID1    str1    234    cond1    0    NA         NA
 ID1    str2    567    cond1    0    ID2,ID3    2
 ID1    str4    123    cond1    0    ID2        1
```

Though `str2` and `567` are present in `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`, the row from `file1.txt` is retained since `col=="cond2"` in `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`. Now the issue is to get those additional columns `col6` and `col7`.  Any idea?

NOTE: This is test case where file1 is compared with file2 and file3. In the real scenario, there will be more files to compare with file.

Comment: Any suggestions to do this would be helpful!!

Comment: Is that desired output accurate for your sample input? Because `str4 123` seems to be non-unique between file1 and file2.

Comment: That has been the real logic here. `str4 123`  becomes unique since `$4!=cond1` in file2. Unique are the ones with either the key in `$2`  and `$3`  not seen in the rest of the files (example 1st row in the desired output) or if the key is found in the remaining files then `$4=cond2` in rest of the files (rows 2 and rows 3 in the output). In the later case, when key is seen and ``$4=cond2` ,  `$6` in the desired output  gives the value from `$1` .

Comment: So lines are unique when `$2`,`$3`, and `$4` differ? But when `$4` is differs (will it always be `cond2` or can it be other values? Does that matter?) then you *also* need to keep the `ID` values from the secondary files for your final output?

Comment: Lines are unique in two cases:1)  `$2`  and `$3`  not seen in secondary files. 2) Even if  `$2`  and `$3`  are seen in secondary files, when `$4==cond2` in secondary files. `$4` has values either `cond1` or `cond2` in all the files. And yes, when `$4==cond2` it needs to keep the `ID` values from secondary files.

Comment: Is it possible for `$4==cond2` to be true for a line A in file1 and to have line A in file# where `$4==cond1`? If so is that unique? (If that isn't possible or if that is unique then your "key" is `$2`/`$3`/`$4` I believe which is a simpler concept to explain and deal with I think.)

Comment: `$4==cond2` is not true for file1 it has only cond1.

Comment: The text ` to delete only if...` immediately made it significantly harder to understand your problem. Don't think in negatives, think and write your  requirements in positives - given input of A, B, C and output of A, C, don't think of it as deleting B think of it as selecting A and C so tell us THAT logic. Negatives are always much harder to understand and they introduce the possibility of the dreaded double negative  - always try to think/use positive logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -vOFS="\t" '!c{c=$0"\tcol6\tcol7";next}NR==FNR{a[$2$3]=$0;next}{if($4=="cond1"){delete a[$2$3]}else{b[$2$3]=b[$2$3]?b[$2$3]","$1:$1}}END{print c;for(i in a){s=split(b[i],t,",");if(!s){b[i]=s="NA"}print a[i],b[i],s}}' a b c
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5    col6    col7
ID1  str2  567  cond1  0        ID2,ID3 2
ID1  str1  234  cond1  0        NA      NA
ID1  str4  123  cond1  1        ID2     1
```

Comment: Thanks. it doesn't work with the original files. Should i send original files?

Comment: @chas What about the original files differs from the example files you put in your post? Showing actual input would help if it differs in some way.